# How to create a buffer around a feature present in a feature collection in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, buffer, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, feature-collection

I am trying to create a buffer of specific radius around a feature present in a feature collection through the following code:

```
var cellular_data= ee.FeatureCollection("users/jazibimran_farmdar/Cellular_Data1");
Map.addLayer(cellular_data, {color: '#FF0000'}, 'Cellular Data');

var UMTS= cellular_data.filter(ee.Filter.eq('GSM', 'UMTS'));
Map.addLayer(UMTS, {color: '#0000FF'}, '3G Tower');

var feature= ee.Feature(UMTS)
var UMTS_Coverage = feature.buffer(2000);
Map.addLayer(UMTS_Coverage, {color: 'brown'},'3G Coverage')
```

but it's giving me the following error:
*Layer error: Feature.buffer: Unable to use a collection in an algorithm that requires a feature or image. This may happen when trying to use a collection of collections where a collection of features is expected; use flatten, or map a function to convert inner collections to features. Use clipToCollection (instead of clip) to clip an image to a collection.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please get the geometry of the feature collection and then apply a buffer

```
var featureCollection = ee.FeatureCollection('');
    var featureColl_to_geometry = FC.geometry();
    var buff = featureColl_to_geometry.buffer(100000)
    Map.addLayer(buff)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/7aa1cd5489f8adba772968e0ede1d585

Comment: It solved the problem.